# Accent issue after migrate Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I had an old Wordpress on a live server. I decided to develop a new wordpress on a dev server.
Now, I want to delete the WP on live server to replace it by the new one. I deleted the old DB and replaced it by the new DB, I deleted all files in old WP and I uploaded all files from the new WP. I modified wp-config.php.

New website appears... But without accent! All my accents are replaced by � in the front and back office. My DB is in ut8.
DB upload was done with HeidiSQL.

It misses some datas too, like articles, options...

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have database backup, your best bet would be importing it from phpmyadmin, easiest thing to do imo. Ofc you'll need to do everything from scratch (clear the existing db).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the [UTF-8 Charset](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/utf-8-encoding-problem) in the meta tags of your header.php

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Then check your  database collation make sure it's utf-8 compatible and not "latin1_swedish_ci"
if not then I'm afraid you are in ["encoding hell"](http://www.whitesmith.co/blog/latin1-to-utf8/)

Comment: Yes the charset is okay

Comment: Then check your  database collation make sure it's utf-8 compatible and not "latin1_swedish_ci"
if not then I'm afraid you are in ["encoding hell"](http://www.whitesmith.co/blog/latin1-to-utf8/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to read this. I tried to import table by table and I obtain an error during wp_option table import. Or this table is working fine on the other server...